# UIView carousel Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am quite new to Xcode. I have seen an example of a horizontal carousel (see screenshot below) which allows to slide through different views. The red box indicates another slide which moves along with the view. I got confused which elements are required to implement such functionality. Please suggest me how should I do it

[image]

Comment: Search on "carousel". There are lots of examples, tutorials, github projects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

The idea is to use an UIPickerView and rotate it 90 Degrees.

```
var pickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerViewContainer: UIView!
var dataHolder = ["...", "July", "August", "This Month", "..."]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Initialization code
    pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 339, height: 60))

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

    pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi / 180))
    pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: -60, y: 0, width: pickerViewContainer.frame.width+120, height: pickerViewContainer.frame.height)

    pickerViewContainer.addSubview(pickerView)
}
```

With that you can scroll horizontal.

Now all you need is to rotate the views for your rows back 90 Degrees.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 50, height: 60))
    view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (-90 * (.pi / 180)))

    let label = UILabel(frame: view.frame)
    label.text = dataHolder[row]
    label.textAlignment = .center
    view.addSubview(label)

    return view
}
```

For sure you need to implement all other datasource and delegate methods like

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dataHolder.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(dataHolder[row])
}
```

Don't forget

> UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource

All you need to do then is to add an UIView to your viewController in storyboard where your picker should be and connect it with the `@IBOutlet weak var pickerViewContainer: UIView!`

Maybe you need to play with the frame numbers in code to show it nicely and adjust the frames for your needs.